# Is there a way to mark the recursive members of a group?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In Powershell there ist the cmdlet "Get-ADGroupMember" and it has the parameter "-Recursive, which can be set or not.

If I execute the command like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity MyGroup -Recursive
```

the output should get me all users, which are somehow, nested group or not, in the group MyGroup. 
Is it possible to "mark" these as nested users?

Comment: It's not clear where you want to mark the users.

Comment: What i thought of: Putting the marked users in a group, like @robliv has done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a straight forward way of doing this. But you can use array subtraction.

```
#gets only non-nested users
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity MyGroup | where {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}

#gets all users including nested ones
$allusers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity MyGroup -Recursive | where {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}

#substracts non-nested users from all users, resulting in an array with only nested users
$NestedUsers = $allusers | Select-String $($users -join "|") -NotMatch
```

Comment: Thx, I will test if I can use this ^^